# Using the Archimedean principle

Tags: real-analysis, discrete-mathematics

How can I use the Archimedean principle to show that there exists an integer $n$ such that $\frac{1}{n}<y-x$ where $x$ and $y$ are real numbers with $0\leq x<y$?

According to the Archimedean principle:
Let $a>0$ and $b \in \mathbb{R}$. There exists an integer $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $b<a\cdot n$.

Comment: How you express the [Archimedean principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedean_property) ?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I added the description in the question now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You apply the definition.  Because $x \lt y, y-x \gt 0$.  Let $y-x$ be the $a$ in the definition and $b$ be $1$.